# JS determine if event.target has "[ref=xxxx]"

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Please advice the way to know that if the event.target is this element which has ref="xxxx"

I tried,

```
if(event.target.hasAttribute("[ref=xxxx]"))
```

, it didnt work.

Thank you very much.

HTML

```
<div ref="xxxx"> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery (based on question tags), you could do something like:

```
if ($(event.target).is("[ref='xxx']")) {  // or possibly $(this)...
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

if you are using jquery, you should use jquery :)

test if the target's ref attribute is 'xxxx'

```
if($(event.target).attr("ref") === "xxxx"){

}
```

or, see if it actually has a `ref` attribute:

```
if($(event.target).filter("*[ref]").length){

}
```

Comment: Any reason for `*[ref]` instead of just `[ref]`?

Comment: I only ever use `*` for `*#duplicate-ids` that I can't avoid

Answer (score 1):

`hasAttribute()` will return a boolean and syntax is `hasAttribute( attributeName)`

You want `getAttribute()`

```
if(event.target.getAttribute("ref") =="xxxx")
```